# NextJS Using a memory cache in dev does not work

Tags: typescript, caching, next.js

I want to make a simple static blog site, and when I export my pages, everything is good and fast.

But in dev mode, my post generation is slow and I want to cache it, so that it is done only once. This is done in a `post.ts` file and my cache is `const posts: Post[] = []` .

What I expect is that after typing `yarn dev`, the `post.ts` file is loaded once and I can fill and reuse my cached post array, but strangely this ts module is loaded many times.

```
import fs from 'fs'
import path from 'path'
// ...
​
console.log('????? reloading page')
const posts: Post[] = []  // cached posts, hope to generate once
let postsGenerated = false
​
export async function getSortedPostsData(): Promise<Post[]> {
  // Get file names under /posts
  const pendings: Promise<any>[] = []
  if (postsGenerated) {
    console.log('+++++ Using cache ')
    return sortPostsByDate(posts)
  } else {
    console.log('==== Calculating all')
    postsGenerated = true
  }
  let i = 0
  traverseDir('content/blog', (path) => {
    if (path.includes('.md')) { ... })
  }
      
  await Promise.all(pendings)
  return sortPostsByDate(posts)
}
```

The result is that sometimes cache is used, sometimes not. Even when reloading the same page, cache is not always  called. Why ? And how to improve that ?

[image]

Comment: Could you provide and minimal reproducible example to further debug this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but this sounds like an use-case where dynamic route and getStaticPaths and getStaticProps could work for you.

getStaticPaths would check the existing files and make routes for them, and getStaticProps would fetch the required post when needed. On export, all are fetched and generated.

https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticpaths-static-generation

Comment: I'm using it, indeed

Comment: If you are using it, then you should be able to generate the post based on the route only on demand, not all at once? Or are you already, and it's slow even generating that one when opening the post page?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably how Fast Refresh works. You can't be sure that the server won't reload a `.ts` file once you start dev. Not sure how much it would improve, but you could try using a file as a cache instead of a bare const to persist the parsed data among reloads.

```
const devPostsCache = 'devPostsCache.json';
export async function getSortedPostsData(): Promise<Post[]> {
  // Get file names under /posts
  const pendings: Promise<any>[] = []
  const postGenerated = fs.existsSync(devPostsCache);
  if (postsGenerated) {
    const posts = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(devPostsCache));
    return sortPostsByDate(posts)
  } else {
    console.log('==== Calculating all')
    postsGenerated = true
  }
  let i = 0
  traverseDir('content/blog', (path) => {
    if (path.includes('.md')) { ... })
  }
  
  // not sure what pending promises exactly do
  // I'll assume you get an array of post
  const parsedPosts = await Promise.all(pendings);
  fs.writeFileSync(devPostsCache, JSON.stringify(parsedPosts));
  return sortPostsByDate(posts)
}
```

and delete it every time you start dev with a `predev` script

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "predev": "rm devPostsCache.json"
  },
```

**UPDATE**

The other approach I found to avoid recompiling the code too often is changing the [onDemandEntries](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/configuring-onDemandEntries) config.

```
module.exports = {
  onDemandEntries: {
    // period (in ms) where the server will keep pages in the buffer
    maxInactiveAge: 360 * 1000,
    // number of pages that should be kept simultaneously without being disposed
    pagesBufferLength: 10,
  },
}
```

The default is `60 * 1000` for maxInactiveAge and 2 for pagesBufferLength.

I also tried changing some webpack configs, but it didn't work because nextjs [recompile the whole thing per request](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/6554).

Comment: Fast refresh appears on the console, and I thought this would be the cause. However it doesn't seem totally consistent.
The file seems much more easier than what I thought first. It's a bit sad as it's not needed for production.